# How can I extend the spacy span of my matching text output to include everything until the next match?

Tags: python, spacy, nlp

I have code that looks like this:

```
data = u"Species:cat color:orange and white with yellow spots number feet: 4"
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

data=data.lower()
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)


terminology_list = [u"species",u"color", u"number feet"]
patterns = list(nlp.tokenizer.pipe(terminology_list))
matcher.add("TerminologyList", None, *patterns)

doc = nlp(data)
for idd, (match_id, start, end) in enumerate(matcher(doc)):
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(span.text)
```

I want to be able to grab everything until the next match. So that the match looks like this:

species:cat

color:orange and white with yellow spots

number feet: 4

I was trying to extend the span but I don't know how to say stop before the next match. I know that I can have it be like span = doc[start:end+4] or something but that is hard-coding how far ahead to go and I won't know how far I should extend the index.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that does not use spaCy.

First I split up the string into token

```py
split = "Species:cat color:orange and white with yellow spots number feet: 4".replace(": ", ":").split()
```

Then I iterate over the list of tokens, save the key, and then merge the values to the key as long, as there is a new key

```py
goal = []
key_value = None
for token in split:
    print(token)
    if ":" in token:
        if key_value:
            goal.append(kv)
            key_value = token
        else:
            key_value = token
    else:
        key_value += " " + token
goal.append(key_value)
goal
>>>
['Species:cat', 'color:orange and white with yellow spots number', 'feet:4']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that spacy matcher orders the indexes of the matched terms even if it finds a term listed in the term list earlier than another term. So I can just end the span up to right before the next matched index.
Code to show what I mean:

```
data = u"Species:cat color:orange and white with yellow spots number feet: 4"
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

data=data.lower()
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

terminology_list = [u"species",u"color", u"number feet"]
patterns = list(nlp.tokenizer.pipe(terminology_list))
matcher.add("Terms", None, *patterns)

doc = nlp(data)
matches=matcher(doc)
matched_phrases={}
for idd, (match_id, start, end) in enumerate(matches):
    key_match = doc[start:end]
    if idd != len(matches)-1:
        end_index=matches[idd+1][1]
    else:
        end_index=len(doc)
    phrase = doc[end:end_index]
    if phrase.text != '':
        matched_phrases[key_match] = phrase

print(matched_phrases)
```